# Normal distribution shapes

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhaGc.png)

Hi everyone

I'm having hard time differentiating between shapes: Symmetric & Skewed 
There are some clear graphs. You don't need to think twice 
But here for example: the histogram makes me really confused
Is it a right skewed? is it symmetric? Totally lost.

I have tried many ways to get the right answers:
1- comparing between mean=26.75 and median=25.5 values
2- calculating the following distances:

```
 a) The distance from the min to the median is (less/equal or greater) 
    than the median to the max.
 b) The distance from the minimum value to Q1 is (less/equal or 
    greater) than the one from Q3 to the max
 c) The distance from Q1 to the median is (less/equal or greater) than 
    the one from the median to Q3
```

It does not lead me to any conclusion

Right skewed: Everything follows the right skewed rules except c)
Symmetric: Looking at the graph, it seems symmetric, but depending on the calculation it is not

Help please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal distribution shapes: symmetric or skewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46359635/normal-distribution-shapes-symmetric-or-skewed)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please don't double-post your questions. You've already posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46359635/normal-distribution-shapes-symmetric-or-skewed). I don't think there is no information in this one that is not present in the one linked. This one will probably be removed in review, but you can do it yourself.