# Normal distribution shapes: symmetric or skewed

Tags: statistics, shapes, normal-distribution

I'm having hard time differentiating between shapes: Symmetric & Skewed There are some clear graphs. You don't need to think twice But here for example: 
[image: Histogram graph]

The histogram makes me really confused Is it a right skewed? is it symmetric?

Totally lost. :(

I have tried many ways to get the right answers:

- comparing between mean=26.75 and median=25.5 values
- calculating the following distances:

  - From min to the median is (less/equal or greater) than the one from
    median to the max.
  - From the min value to Q1 is (less/equal or greater) than the one from
    Q3 to the max.
  - From Q1 to the median is (less/equal or greater) than the one from
    the median to Q3.

It does not lead me to any conclusion.

Right skewed: Everything follows the right skewed rules except c)

Symmetric: Looking at the graph, it seems symmetric, but depending on the calculation it is not.

Help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, I'd suggest you check for normality using `qqplot` and `shapiro.test` to check for normality. I think the result will be that the data is normal, thus symmetric. If it is not, then you should consider it skewed to the right. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you looking for a test for symmetric vs skewed distribution?  Or normal (= always symmetric) vs non-normal distribution?